# Vertically center a link within a div

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list...

```
<ul class="hide">
  <li class="home">
    <div class="link">
      <a href="/">Home</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="about">
    <div class="link">
      <a href="/about">About Our Community</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="contact">
    <div class="link">
      <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS looks like this....

```
#sitenav ul li .link a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 3px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

But the margins do not center the link vertically

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the link-text always in one line, or should it look good if a line-break occurs?

Comment: If your links will be one line only - http://jsfiddle.net/SE7aB/

Comment: Why do you have a div in there? You could style the li directly... Also, please provide a fiddle with the code that is causing the link to be "unaligned"

Comment: It is just justifying to the top, the div is in there in case I add more data to the list item, it should look good if line breaks occur. Zoltan, how will this statically defined 50px effect the site when it is on smaller devices? Currently this is responsive and I am trying to avoid actual pixel counts (unless it is 1 or 2 pxs). I tried line-height: 100% but no luck

Comment: @Jackie Did any answer below solve your problem?

Comment: 6 different method of vertical centering
 http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This solution could work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/WLQAS/8/

`margin-top: auto;` and `margin-bottom: auto;` don't work to align vertically the objects.

**Updated CSS**

```
li {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 3px;    
}

.link {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I want to have them be one one "line" so if I change it by adding a width:20% It breaks it again... http://jsfiddle.net/WLQAS/2/

Comment: @Jackie I think this answer solves your problem. You can adjust Luis' code so that it is on one line: http://jsfiddle.net/WLQAS/7/. As long as the container is wide enough to hold the content, it should be on one line.

Comment: The problem here would be no universal width, also I am not sure it would be a good idea to limit the text to one line if it is on a small screen.

Comment: Thx khaled_webdev for the corrections, adding the suggestion that @Shredder made, I did the last edit on this answer. Does all this solve the question Jackie ?

Comment: Possible to wrap the text in a way it only fits the container size?

Comment: 2 problems with this way still (8) 1.) Text has to be on same line, I want it to overflow into the next one. 2.) I still need a declared pixel value

Comment: @Khled not a bad solution very pragmatic, this may work as a "no other option" but I would like to keep all text within the <a> tag if possible

Answer (score 4):

Here's a cross browser compatible solution for vertical aligning an `a`-element with an unknown height within a `div`:

**Works** with link texts with and without line-breaks.

**CSS**

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

ul {}
ul li {
    display: table;
    height: 75px;
    #position: relative; /* ie hack */
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

ul li div {
    #position: absolute; /* ie hack */
    #top: 50%; /* ie hack */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul li div a {
    #position: relative; /* ie hack */
    #top: -50%; /* ie hack */
    border: 1px solid green
}
```

It's not recommended to use CSS hacks here, use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ahdzg/1/
**More infos about this trick**: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Hope this helps. Otherwise feel free to ask.

Comment: I converted the li's elements to div's and it still works great.

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent_div{display:table;}.child_div{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;}
```

Then put your link inside the child div.